# Kill buffer when closing emacs with emacsclient

Tags: emacsclient

I am using emacs for writing email with mutt. Email are stored in /tmp even after I sent them (until /tmp is cleared). Since I start emacs with `emacs--daemon`, I have all the emails I have written during the session opened as buffers when launching emacsclient.

I don't like this behavior. I would like emacs to kill the opened buffer when `C-c C-x` is pressed (and to not have this buffer charged when open a new window of emacs with emacsclient.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `server-kill-new-buffers` is `t` (the default) and finish editing with `C-x #` instead of `C-c C-x`.

This calls `server-edit`. I cite the relevant part of it's doc string here:

> Switch to next server editing buffer; say "Done" for current buffer.
>   If a server buffer is current, it is marked "done" and optionally saved.
>   The buffer is also killed if it did not exist before the clients asked for it.
>   When all of a client’s buffers are marked as "done", the client is notified.

If there just one buffer associated with the client that buffer is killed and the terminal of the client is closed.