# How to keep buffers when closing only Emacs client?

Tags: buffers, emacs-daemon, server

I use Emacs 29.1.

When I open Emacsclient, I do it with the following command:

```
emacsclient -a -c --create-frame --no-wait
```

This is bounded to a key combination to start the Emacsclient.

To kill a Emacsclient window, this is bounded to the 'kill' command in a keybinding.

When I open Emacsclient, and visit a file `foobar.txt`. A buffer is created in the first client.
Then I open a second client, without closing the first client.And in the second client I open the same buffer `foobar.txt`. Then I close the second client window.
When I open a new Emacsclient window, I can see the buffer `foobar.txt` is still open in background.
When closing the second and the first one Emacsclient, then the buffer `foobar.txt` will disappear.

I want to keep the buffer `foobar.txt`, regardless if the client windows are open or not. The buffer `foobar.txt` should be staying in the Emacs daemon.

When looking for a solution, I found another this thread:
[Kill buffer when closing emacs with emacsclient](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37152/kill-buffer-when-closing-emacs-with-emacsclient)

When checking `server-kill-new-buffers`, this is set on `t`.

I set this in Emacs client window on `nil`:
[image]

Then I visit the file `foobar.txt` again, and close the Emacsclient.

When open another Emacsclient instance, I see the buffer `foobar.txt` is not saved in memory.

TLDR: How can I keep the buffer sticking to Emacs daemon, when closing the only Emacsdaemon window with `kill` command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76968294/20212483 may help

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my issue since I open Emacsclient in other viewports than the current emacsclient, under a keybinding which opens a new Emacsclient window.